# Отпрaвка ответа клиенту с результатами работы функции

Tags: javascript, node.js

Если `request` поместить в `app.get`, то всегда будет возвращаться пустая страница, а если поместить `request` перед `app.get` то значение будет отправлено клиенту.
**Вопрос:** как заставить `app.get` подождать пока request сделает свою работу и лишь тогда отправлять данные?

```
var express = require('express');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();
var text;
var headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
};
var options = {
    url:'http://www.worldtimeserver.com/',
    headers:headers
};     
request(options,function(err,res,body) {
            $ = cheerio.load(body);
           text=( $('h1').text() );
});  
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send(text);
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну не дубликат же...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Немного магии:

```
var express = require('express'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    request = require('request'),
    events = require('events'); // Это встроенный модуль
var app = express();
var text;
text_state = new events.EventEmitter; // Нам понадобится событие "текст загружен"

var headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
};
var options = {
    url:'http://www.worldtimeserver.com/',
    headers:headers
};
request(options,function(err,res,body) {
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    text=$('h1').text();
    text_state.emit('ready'); // Вызываем событие загрузки
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if(text){ // если текст еще не загружен - то он undefined, так что мы идём и ждем события загрузки
        res.send(text);
    }else{
        text_state.on('ready',() => {
            res.send(text);
        });
    }
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Comment: А объяснений магии не будет?

Comment: Пояснения в комментариях в коде

Answer (score 0):

А если засунуть request (вместе с options и headers) в обработчик app.get (перед res.send) разве он не будет именно так и делать?

P.S. Попробовал с промисом, конечно, чисто для интересу:
`var express = require('express'),
    cheerio = require('cheerio'),
    request = require('request');
var app = express();
var text;`

`var headers = {
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'
};`

`var options = {
    url:'http://www.worldtimeserver.com/',
    headers:headers
};`

`request(options,function(err,res,body) {
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    text=$('h1').text();
});
app.get('/', function (req, res) {`

```
new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(text);
}).then(text => res.send(text));
```

});

`app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
});`

Только лень въезжать, как блок скрипта вставить. Объяснил бы кто, что ли.

Comment: Это будет работать, но запрос будет уходить каждый раз при заходе на страницу. Если там статический текст - это излишне

Comment: Может, попробовать тогда, чёрт возьми, таки завернуть текст в промис:    `new Promise(function(resolve) { ... resolve(text); }).then(text => res.send(text););`